# Opportunity Owner change in apex trigger shows 'The requested resource does not exist' on details page

Tags: apex, trigger, error, before-trigger, error-messages

On selecting a stage between junk or dnd , the owner of opportunity is changed to admin user. The OWD for opportunity is private, so if ownership is changed then he loses access to the opportunity.

In before update of opportunity, following code gets executed-

```
if(oldMapValues.get(opp.id).StageName <> opp.StageName){
     if(opp.StageName=='Junk' || opp.StageName=='DND'){                    
           opp.OwnerId = System.Label.AdminId;
      }
 }
```

If user is other than admin, he gets the following error on the edit page-

[image]

Similar way this code was tested in after update as well, but as you update the opportunity twice it again goes into trigger and the error is shown.

Is there any way to not show this error and save and close the opportunity.

Comment: Maybe you should do this bit as an `@future` method. Because you've changed the owner, and as the user can only save her own opportunities... she won't be able to save (or see this one)

Comment: What is the user license and share the opportunity object permission on the user's profile?

Comment: Salesforce license is used. For profile create,read,edit access is given, no Viewall given because data is needed to be restricted.

Comment: @future works the same, and Unable to load is shown, and that error is also shown on current page.